# Why in React are curly brackets needed when passing props as an argument to a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I don't understand why prop arguments need to be enclosed in curly brackets.  Can anyone explain why?  Consider the following three components.  Kid renders correctly (it passes the prop in curly brackets).  But Kid2 does not (it doesn't use curly brackets).  Why are the curly brackets needed?

```
import "./styles.css";
import Kid from "./Kid";
import Kid2 from "./Kid2";

const person = { nombre: "Joe" };
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>In App Component</h1>
      <Kid person={person}></Kid>
      <Kid2 person={person}></Kid2>
    </div>
  );
}


import "./styles.css";
//curly brackets used in argument
export default function Kid({ person }) {
  return (
    <div className="SubComp">
      <h1>Name is: {person.nombre}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}


import "./styles.css";
//NO curly brackets used in argument
export default function Kid2(person) {
  return (
    <div className="SubComp">
      <h1>Name is: {person.nombre}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/3-component-subcomponent-props-forked-k0iqdq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let me first ask you - how familiar are you with [the concept of destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?

Comment: @Dai is hitting the nail on the head. When react goes to render your component it passes an object containing all properties as the first parameter. The braces are just destructuring the props parameter.

Comment: Some.  I believe destructuring is happening when one clones something with the spread operator like so:  const array = [1, 2, 3]
const arrayClone = [...array]

Comment: `<Kid person={person}></Kid>` <-- On this line, see how you're assigning `person` (the `const` `object` variable) to the `person=""` attribute - consider that JS has no way of mapping a _named_ Component JSX attribute name (`person=""`) to a _positional_ function parameter (JS doesn't expose function parameter names) - hence why it has to map `person=""` to an object property with the same name - then it passes that entire object in as a single function parameter argument.

Comment: This seems quirky.  In javascript you  can create a function with an argument and then call that function like so:  function greet(name){}  greet('yo').  I thought tags and components worked similarly.  Apparently they don't.

Comment: To add to my last comment.  One can treat them as roughly analogous -- as long as you just pass the props as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your component is going to be passed an object which contains all of the props. You don't need to use curly brackets, but you do need to treat it as the object it is. So if you like, you can do this:

```
export default function Kid(props) {
  const person = props.person;
```

As a shorthand, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the assignment:

```
export default function Kid(props) {
  const { person } = props;
```

And as an even shorter hand, you can move the destructuring into the argument list

```
export default function Kid({ person }) {
```

And that's the version you'll see most people do, just because it's convenient.

Comment: Oh.  I like this answer.  I'm going to just stick with passing the props in as the argument. Then I can forget about the curly braces.  The other short hand methods definitely compromise readability and comprehension.

Comment: Thank you I've also revised the codesandbox to illustrate your first "passing the prop" approach.